# MJPEG streaming over RTSP

Tags: ffmpeg, rtp, libavcodec

I am capturing JPEG images from an IP-camera over RTSP. I use live555 + libavcodec for streaming and decoding the MJPEG image. The stream works fine up to the image resolution 2048 x 1920. But when I increase the image width above 2048, I get a bar-shaped rectangular image of very small width (i.e., 544x1920). The image is correctly captured and saved on the camera. The problem occurs only when I stream the image over RTSP to the PC. Is there any payload restriction in RTP for high-resolution MJPEG?

Comment: oooh great.can you please share how you get JPEG images over RTSP? I was success to transport data from an IP camera over RTSP by SharpRTSP that is transport layer but can't understand how decoding that to MJPEG? thanks for any idea

Answer (score 8):

Please read https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2435 at the bottom of page 4. There, it is written that the maximum width of an image is 2040. A workaround is made possible with the ONVIF standard.

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question. I wonder why it hasn't been accepted ...

Answer (score 0):

More likely, either decoder incorrectly decodes the image, or RTP client incorrectly reconstructs it. 2048 pixels is not a limit for JPEG (obviously) and RTP client does not deal a lot with parsing the bitstream, so resolution is not so important there (also the process reaches decoded image and does not fail completely on the way!).